# UINavigation Breaks on landscape mode in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Good afternoon community,

I have a problem with my app, I am trying to make it look good in both situations, so when I change orientation my app returns to the main screen, it does not stay on the second screen, will someone have a solution to this problem?

I don't know if my view breaks or cannot cover the space that I have determined, I leave my code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

init() {
         UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
         UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
         UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = true
         UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .clear
         UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }


var backButton : some View {
    Button(action: {
       self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
       }) {
           HStack {
           Image("Backarrow")
               .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
               .foregroundColor(.white)
               Text(" Back")
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
           }
       }
   }

var topImage:some View{
        Image("header2")
            .resizable()
            .overlay( ImageOverlay() , alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.black)
}

var usernameTextField:some View{
    
        HStack{
            TextField("", text: $LoginViewM.username)
                .placeholder(Text("Numero de telefono,email o usuario").padding().foregroundColor(.white), show: LoginViewM.password.isEmpty)
                .background(Color.black)
            Image("menuCloseSmall")
                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 14))
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
         .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", fixedSize: 16.4))
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3))
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
   }

var errorUsernameLabel:some View{
    VStack{
        Text("    Hey you, no user found. Make sure you’ve provided the ")
            .lineLimit(1)
           Text("correct information.")
    }
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .foregroundColor(.redBlueParrot)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
    .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12.1))
}

var passwordTextField:some View{
    HStack{
        TextField("Contraseña", text: $LoginViewM.password)
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", fixedSize: 16.4))
            .padding(.bottom)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .placeholder(Text("Contraseña").padding().foregroundColor(.white), show: LoginViewM.username.isEmpty)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
            .background(Color.black)
        Image("editShow")
            .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 14))
    }
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3))
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))   
  }

var errorPasswordLabel:some View{
    VStack{
        Text("      Incorrect password for \(LoginViewM.password). Please try again.")
    }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
        .foregroundColor(.redBlueParrot)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 12.1))
}
var buttonLogin:some View{
    
    NavigationLink(
        destination: Text("Hola"),
        label: {
            Text("Iniciar sesion")
        })            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Medium", size: 16))
        .foregroundColor(Color.ligthGray)
        .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 174, maxWidth: 174, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: 48, maxHeight: 48, alignment: .center)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
        .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1.5))
        
    
}

var textInBottom:some View{
    
    HStack(spacing:5){
        Text("Olvidaste tu")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
        Button("contraseña"){
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
        Text("o")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
        Button("usuario"){
            
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        .font(.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 16))
    }
}


@ObservedObject var LoginViewM = LoginViewModel()

var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader{ geometry in
        NavigationView{
            VStack(spacing:2){
                topImage
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height * 0.39)
                
                VStack(spacing:17){
                    usernameTextField
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.90, height: geometry.size.height*0.05)
                    errorUsernameLabel
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.90,height: geometry.size.height*0.06, alignment: .center)
                    
                    passwordTextField
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width*0.90, height: geometry.size.height*0.05)
                
                    errorPasswordLabel
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height*0.06, alignment: .center)
                    
                }.frame( height: geometry.size.height * 0.40)
               
                VStack{
                    buttonLogin
                }.frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.10, alignment: .center)
                
                Spacer()
                textInBottom
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.05, alignment: .center)
                Spacer()
                        
            }

            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            .background(Color.black)
        }
         .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
       .background(Color.black)
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
       
  }

 }
    
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    LoginView()
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`?

Comment: thanks a lot @jnpdx, but what is the difference betweenn both?

Comment: Did it work? If so, I'll write it up as an answer. Link for now: https://www.donnywals.com/whats-the-difference-between-stateobject-and-observedobject/